# catcon.pl: Base for log file names must be supplied

Tags: perl, installation, oracle19c

I run oracle Databse 19.13 in Windows and get this error when i want install DBMS_CLOUD Package use `catcon.pl` see [*"DBMS_CLOUD : Installation on 19c and 21c On-Prem Databases"*](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/dbms_cloud-installation):

```sh
C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\dbhome_1\perl\bin\perl
C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\admin\catcon.pl -u sys/****** --force_pdb_mode 'READ WRITE' -b dbms_cloud_install -d "C:\app" -l "C:\app" dbms_cloud_install.sql
```

Followed by the error

> Base for log file names must be supplied at C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\admin\catcon.pl line 482.

I'm not sure how to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

[Judging by the argument information provided here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_catcon.pl.htm), you need to provide the mandatory `-b` argument

> `-b` (Mandatory) The base name for log file names

You can see that argument used in the link you provided in your question

```sh
$ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin/perl $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/catcon.pl \
  ...
  -b dbms_cloud_install \
  ...
```

Comment: as you can see the madatory -b argument is provided in my command

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you should use double quotes instead of single quote, so the real question in your command line is, the force_pdb_mode should followed by double quotes params
So change your command line to this:

```
C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\admin\catcon.pl -u sys/****** --force_pdb_mode "READ WRITE" -b dbms_cloud_install -d "C:\app" -l "C:\app" dbms_cloud_install.sql
```

This will work.
And by the way, for params without a space, like UPGRADE, you can use it directly with out any quotes.